# How to change folder/file permission through Windows Service

Tags: c#, winforms, service

I have coded a file convertor which converts dwfx file to tiff format. It has two ways of operation. First is manual conversion in which the user selects the input folder and the output folder and the files get converted even if the destination or source folder has read only attributes. Second is run through service in which the conversion takes place as a service. The problem I am facing here is that whenever I do the same process as service it shows access denied with the read only files. I tried removing or changing the attributes through code but it showed `system.unauthorized access exception`. I also tried making the application a full trust application so an app.manifest was added to it still the event logs showed the same error. I am running the service as local account which has administrator priviliges. I dont understand what to do.

My code is

```
private bool GetFolderAccess(string sDirectory)
        {            
            try
            {
                //Commented lines are for changing the permission when the exception is thrown everytime.
                /*DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(sDirectory);
                WindowsIdentity self = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
                DirectorySecurity ds = info.GetAccessControl();
                ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(self.Name,FileSystemRights.FullControl,InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit |InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit,PropagationFlags.None,AccessControlType.Allow));
                info.SetAccessControl(ds); */        
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(sDirectory + "testfile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter(fs);                
                s.Dispose();
                File.Delete(sDirectory + "\\testfile.txt");
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                eventLog1.WriteEntry(ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }

        }
```

Please advice me what to do. Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [File.SetAttribute Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and give various [FileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). 
You can also use [GetAccessControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.getaccesscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Here is an example:

```
public static bool HasWritePermissionOnDir(string path)
{
var writeAllow = false;
var writeDeny = false;
var accessControlList = Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
if (accessControlList == null)
    return false;
var accessRules = accessControlList.GetAccessRules(true, true, 
                            typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));
if (accessRules ==null)
    return false;

foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in accessRules)
{
    if ((FileSystemRights.Write & rule.FileSystemRights) != FileSystemRights.Write) 
        continue;

    if (rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Allow)
        writeAllow = true;
    else if (rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Deny)
        writeDeny = true;
}

return writeAllow && !writeDeny;
}
```

**EDIT:**

To change permission:

```
    FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(path);

    if ((attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
    {
        // Remove read only property of the file.
        File.SetAttributes(file, attributes & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
    }
```

Also, try to run your Visual Studio in Admin mode

**EDIT2:**

You may also use:

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(pathToAFile);
fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
fileInfo.Refresh();
```

Comment: what is removeattribute?? It says it does not exist in the current context

Comment: please add 
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

Comment: Check the new code, you can use ~ instead of RemoveAttribute.